# Is it better practice to pass data into a model method from the controller or requery the database in the method for the information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, parameter-passing

What's the best practice to get information into a model method from the controller? Should you pass the information as a parameter or requery the database in the model? For instance,

Method #1

*magazines_controller.rb*

```
@magazine = Magazine.find(article.magazine_id)
articles_method(@magazine)
```

Method #2

*magazine.rb*

```
def articles_method
  magazine = Magazine.find(self.magazine_id)
end
```

My guess is passing it as a parameter. If so, are there any cases where requerying the database is better? Like if there are large collections that need to be passed?

Comment: +1, other Steve! I've been passing instances back and forth to stay out of the DB, but I have if that's the best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very broad so I'll try to answer with a few scenarios. Generally I don't like making other queries in my models, in order to decouple them when they're not explicitly related (they're already associations declared in the model class). In the cases where something needs to happen across very different models I'll pass just the values I need into the method that will be doing the work. To use your example, if I had an `articles_method` which needs, say, the pages of a magazine, I'd pass the pages in rather than the whole magazine object. Pass just what the method needs and nothing more

Method #1

_magazines_controller.rb_

```
@magazine = Magazine.find(article.magazine_id)
articles_method(@magazine.pages, @magazine.metadata)
```

Keep the interface simple and pass values in rather the models.

Other cases include passing ids into asynchronous method calls, e.g. delayed job, sidekiq. In this case you would want your method to do the database query in order to grab the most recent version of the object at the time the method executes. So passing in an id to your async method would be better than passing the actual model or even the values - those values might have been updated shortly before the async method ran.

When your method is calling out to many models, or you're passing in many object and/or values; I'd instead implement the service object or interactor pattern and create a new class to be responsible for this interaction. Instantiate it with references to every model involved (either by id and requery, serialization, or directly passing the object in) and then have the service/interactor do the work in a `run` or `perform` method `PageFooterPrinter.new(mag.pages, other_obj.stuff).run`.